# Network still clogged after update with new fee structure in 2021?

Tags: transactions, cpu, stake

I'm trying to make a trade on NewDex exchange and I have 100 EOS staked, but I run out of CPU after 1 transaction. How much EOS do I really need staked in order to at least make 5-10 trades? It's kind of ridiculous after 1+ year where the system is still clogged. What are some other proposed solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

With the new resource-model staking will not give you CPU anymore. You have to powerup CPU on a daily basis now, which means you are paying for a specific amount of CPU within a 24h period.

Use https://eospowerup.io/free to get free CPU.

Comment: You can also pay for power up here: https://eosauthority.com/power